# Javascript: play a random song from an array (list)

Tags: javascript, audio, random, shuffle

I want to play a random song in a website. The tunes are short (max a few seconds, they don't need preload or buffering).

This part works, the number of songs may be unlimited, because `tunes.length` automatically counts all songs.

`document.write` displays the URL of a random song URL on the screen

```
tunes = new Array(
'"http://example.net/abcd.ogg"',
'"http://example.net/efgh.ogg"',
'"http://example.net/ijkl.ogg"'
)
var audiopath = (tunes[Math.floor(Math.random() * tunes.length)])
document.write (audiopath)
```

This part works too, when the URL is defined as a constant.

```
var song = new audio('http://example.net/abcd.ogg');
song.play();
```

When I try to replace the constant URL with the variable `audiopath`, it fails to play. 
May it be anything wrong with the syntax? 
I tried to run it with and without single quotes in the URL `'"http://example.net/ijkl.ogg"'` or `"http://example.net/ijkl.ogg"`

```
var song = new audio(audiopath);
song.play();
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be better to handle starting playback once the song has fully loaded. Something like this:

```
let loaded = false;
const song = new Audio();

song.addEventListener('loadeddata', function() 
{
    loaded = true;
    song.play();
}, false);

song.addEventListener('error' , function() 
{
    alert('error loading audio');
}, false);

song.src = tunes[Math.floor(Math.random() * tunes.length)];
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try it. It looks more universal for longer songs.

I've done it differently, saving the random / shuffle function as a separate .js file and using this as the audio source in the player. 

The .html file calls 

    <script language="JavaScript" src="rndorder.js">
    var audio = new Audio("rndorder.js" );
    audio.play(); 
    </script>

The .js file returns 

    var audio = new Audio(tunes[Math.floor(Math.random() * tunes.length)])

(I don't even know if this line was necessary in the .js file, but it works).